# Adding stability to MPM simulation?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, computational-geometry

I am writing a 2D implementation of MLS-MPM, I have fluids working perfetly fine, solids technically work as well, at low time steps.

This is the fluid simulation at a large time step:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLnY9.jpg

And this is a pciture of the solids at a low time step after a large amount of simulation:
[image]

I am running into the following problem, the MLS-MPM method uses a deformation matrix for particles who are meant to remain solid. At large time steps the inaccuracies cause this matrix to become degenerate and my simulation explodes.

This is a rust implementation of the critical part where the problem happens:

```rust
let volume = particle.mass / density;

            let j: f32 = properties.deformation_gradient.determinant();

            assert!(j > 0.0, "{}", properties.deformation_gradient);
            let volume_scaled = volume * j;

            let f_t = properties.deformation_gradient.transpose();
            let f_inv_t = f_t.try_inverse().unwrap_or(Mat2::identity());
            let f_minus_f_inv_t = properties.deformation_gradient - f_inv_t;

            let p_term_0 = properties.elastic_mu * f_minus_f_inv_t;
            let p_term_1 = properties.elastic_lambda * j.ln() * f_inv_t;
            let p_combined = p_term_0 + p_term_1;

            let stress = (1.0 / j) * p_combined * f_t;
            let eq_16_term_0 = -volume_scaled * 4.0 * stress * self.simulation_speed;
```

Which I have taken from [here](https://github.com/robkau/mlsmpm-particles-rs/blob/main/src/step_p2g.rs#L11) who got it from [this tutorial](https://nialltl.neocities.org/articles/mpm_guide) who modified it from the original [paper's author](https://github.com/yuanming-hu/taichi_mpm/blob/master/mls-mpm88-explained.cpp).

The short of it is, it seems that large timesteps make the deformation matrix flip from a positive determinant to a negative determinant. SInce this code uses logarithms, that negative determinant is a no-no, as it destroys everything.

I was wondering if there is a way for me to get numerical stability at larger time steps. I am fine sacrificing accuracy as this is for a toy implementation.

Comment: Negative deformation gradients occur due to the way velocity gradients are computed.  You have to use 1) a more accurate way of computing the deformation gradient 2) make sure that the updated Lagrangian formulation uses the correct quantities 3) something like CPDI which keeps track of particle geometries, etc. to reduce that.  You cannot avoid it for very large deformations and will have to use a purely eulerian approach.

Comment: What other methods could I use to obtain teh deformation gradient that would be more accurate?

Comment: What is "MLS-MPM"?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth a 2018 Siggraph paper.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Moving least squares material point method.

Comment: @Makogan:  Element inversion is a discretization problem and can be reduced by refinement.  It cannot be completely eliminated in Lagrangian numerical methods.  But one can make sure that the updated Lagrangian formulation is correct (derive it yourself and don't follow books/papers, you will see the problem in the literature).

Comment: continued...

The deformation gradient assumes the velocity gradient is constant over a time step.  That leads to errors.  The most common error is that all quantities in a formulation are not evaluated at the same point in time.  For a constant velocity gradient, only one term of the expansion of the exponential map is used.  You can do better (see the famous paper on several ways of evaluating the exponential of a matrix).